# How to store tags for a blog article in SQL database?

Tags: mysql, sql, blogs

I currently am working on developing a blogging website. For this application we're using MySQL as the database. For this application,I created a blog table which contains the following properties:

- id
- blog_title
- content
- user_id
- updated_at
- upvotes

I want to add **tags** to this table. What is the recommended way of adding tags to this table so that in the application I can search for articles/blogs based on **tags** ?

Comment: Assuming you want to conform to [the rules of database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization): you should not add tags to your `blog` table because tags represent a many-to-many taxonomy. You need two new separate tables: `tags` and `article-tags`.

Comment: Thank you, also I wanted to add featured image for the blog. Is it okay to save all the featured images in the database? or I need to store the featured images in the front-end?

Comment: Store image files in a file store such as Amazon S3 or Azure Blob Storage. I do not recommend ever saving files to your website’s file system because of inherent security risks. You could save images to binary columns in your database but this will have poor performance compared to alternatives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is common to use many-to-many relationship for tags. In your case it can be a couple of tables:

tags

- id
- name

tag_blog

- tag_id (foreign key to tags)
- article_id (foreign key to articles)

You can set combination of (tag_id, article_id) as primary key. In this case it will be guaranteed that tag can be mentioned only once for the given article.